# How to execute commands on modifier key press and release?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xbindkeys

I'd like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to run a start command (let's say record) on **key press**. I'd also like to run a stop command on **key release**. In addition, I want to maintain <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as a modifier (e.g. allow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste).

I've tried`xbindkeys` but it only detects key events when the modifier key is combined with a normal key.

I also know `xinput test <keyboard_id>` could be used to capture and read modifier key events but I'm not sure how to do it or if it is even a viable option.

Any help?

Comment: Nothing is impossible, but you wouldn't want to give pressing Ctrl an action globally. It is part of many, many other actions, both globally and application- specific.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Well I use "record" as example because it's a simpler example, but in reality, I want to run a command which *swaps space and shift on key press and back on key release* via `setxkbmap -symbols "...+swap_shift_space"`

This is because I use the `CapsLock` key as Ctrl so it would be more comfortable to use `space` key as Shift for Ctrl+Shift shortcuts.